# Can I configure vim to set noswapfile when editing a file that exists in a git repo

Tags: vim

What vim APIs and facilities could I use to disable vim swapfile (the hidden recovery file) for a given buffer if the file exists in a git repo?

Inside git repos I also want to enable an autosave plugin, since I don't need to worry about accidental changes getting saved.  But for other buffers outside of git repos I don't want autosave to accidentally modify files, and I want to keep the vim recovery file.

I suppose this is a nice plugin programming task to get familiar with vim plugin programming but if anyone knows roughly what approach i should take I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Disabling swapfile

For existing buffers, you can `:setlocal noswapfile`. This will remove any existing one and turn recovery off. When opening new buffers, you can also directly prepend `:noswapfile edit ...`

#### Detecting Git repository

If you always open Vim from the Git root directory, this can be as simple as `isdirectory('.git')`. Else, you'd have to also check parent directories:

```
let gitDirspec = finddir('.git', '.;')
let isGitRepo = !empty(gitDirspec)
```

Alternatively, the [vcscommand.vim plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vcscommand.vim) provides detection for various revision control system types (Git among them):

```
let isGitRepo = VCSCommandGetVCSType('') ==? 'git'
```

#### Hooking it up

If you had a static list of Git repositories, you could put the paths directly into `:autocmd` filespec patterns:

```
:autocmd BufNew,BufRead /path/to/repo1/**,/path/to/repo2/** setlocal noswapfile
```

In order to run the detection, we need to run the autocmds on each opened file:

```
:autocmd BufNew,BufRead * if VCSCommandGetVCSType('') ==? 'git' | setlocal noswapfile | endif
```